# EmberJS, WordPress REST API and categories and tags

Tags: wordpress, ember.js

I’ve started playing with ember and trying to combine the WordPress REST API and EmberJS. I‘m stucking with this problem: I want ember to show me all WordPress posts from a certain category or tag.

I have a route that shows me all categories `routes/categories.js` that are in the category model `models/category.js`.
Now I need a route for each category `routes/categories/category.js`, that shows me all posts within a certain category.

`post` and `category` are two models, that I need to get combined I guess, but I do not know how ...

In `routes/categories.js` I have something like this

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      categories: this.store.findAll('category'),
      posts: this.store.findAll('post')
    });
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(...arguments);
    Ember.set(controller, 'categories', model.categories);
    Ember.set(controller, 'posts', model.posts);
  }
});
```

And in `templates/categories.hbs` this

```
<p>List of all categories in the model</p>
<ul>
    {{#each categories as |category|}}
        <li>{{link-to category.name 'categories.category' category}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Now I want to see all posts that are in this category 
`routes/categories/category.js`

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params) {

        ...???...

    }
});
```

and in `templates/categories/category.hbs` ?

```
<h3>List all posts from the selected category</h3>
<ul>
    {{#each posts as |post|}}
        <li>{{link-to post.title 'posts.post' post}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Someone able to help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is query all posts filtered by category. First find the endpoint with the data you need.

To filter posts by category with the WP-API you can do:

`example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=99&filter[category_name=my-category]`

To pass the category to the route's model we need a dynamic route. For instance:

`this.route('category', {path: 'categories/:slug'});`

… which would turn into example.com/categories/food. The corresponding ember-data method would be:

`model(params) {
  return this.store.query('post', {per_page: 99, filter: {category_name: params.slug}});
}`

I made a full example here: http://ember-wordpress.surge.sh/.

The (documented) source code is here https://github.com/oskarrough/ember-wordpress/, in the tests/dummy folder.

Comment: Great, this works! I did not know that it is possible to filter the WP-API endpoints directly, thought I need to filter inside the app. Thanks a lot!